# R - subset of a dataset that contains no "NA" or "null"

Tags: r, dataset, subset

I have a dataset `a`and I would like to get all lines from 1 - 10000 that contain no "NA" or "null".
They way I've read my dataset is this:

```
a<- read.table("GDS4879.CLEAN", header = TRUE, na.strings = NA)
```

Is it possible to do this using R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you want to clear all NAs from the dataset. You can achieve that by using [complete.cases](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/complete.cases.html)

```
a[complete.cases(a),]
```

Then use the head function to get the first 10000

```
a <- head(a,10000)
```

Comment: How would this code (using `complete.cases`) remove rows with "null" entries as character unless you specify those as NA strings as in the answer by digEmAll?

Comment: @docendodiscimus When I read the table I use this `na.strings = NA` . This sets these values to NA.

Comment: @docendodiscimus I just got what you meant. You mean that if my values are marked as null on the read file I won't be able to get those. Thing is the way that I've set it up, using NA without using the quotes works the same.

Answer (score 3):

Pass `"NA"` and `"null"` to `na.strings` parameter, then after reading the file call `na.omit()`.

Example :
 (here I read the table from a string, but you can easily change the code to read your file)

```
text <- 
"A,B,C,D
NA,1,2,3
4,5,6,7
8,9,10,11
12,13,null,14"

a <- read.table(text=text, header=TRUE, sep=',',row.names=NULL,
                na.strings = c('NA','null')) # this parameter turns "NA" and "null" strings to NA values

a <- na.omit(a) # this removes the strings containing NAs

> a
  A B  C  D
2 4 5  6  7
3 8 9 10 11
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped understand a little bit more. I am going to choose my answer because I think it answers directly to the question that I've asked, and I think that my answer is more clear and easy way to do it.

Comment: @Konstantinos - Why not solve the problem initially upon reading, rather than having another unnecessary step in the code?

Comment: I think you meant *rows* for *strings* in `# this removes the strings containing NAs`

Comment: @RichardScriven didn't know this was an option. Thanks for your advice.